# How to retrieve a parameter value based on a result set from stored procedure in SSRS 2014?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, business-intelligence, ssrs-2014

I would like to know how do I select a parameter based on the result set from a stored procedure.

My code looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UserInformation (@ReportRunDate DATE = NULL) 
AS
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT -- some fields
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE RegisteredDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ReportRunDate) - 2, -1)
--I'll output the result set after applying all the logic like

SELECT UserID, UserName, DOJ
FROM CTE
```

Now, when the user selects the date on the report, I created another parameter and trying to retrieve records from the "Available Values" using 'Get values from a query'. I would like to show the list of UserIDs from the above query result set and allow the user SELECT based on that.

[image: Parameters]

[image: Available Values for Parameters]

[image: Values from Query]

[image: Design View]

[image: 5th image]

**UPDATE:** I have created another stored procedure as there is no other alternative. Now my question is, how do I pass the second stored procedure value to the first one in WHERE clause?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UserInformation (@ReportRunDate DATE = NULL) 
AS
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT -- some fields
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE RegisteredDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ReportRunDate) - 2, -1)
--I'll output the result set after applying all the logic like

SELECT User_ID, UserName, DOJ
FROM CTE
WHERE User_ID = EXEC usp_Get_UserID
```

I am looking for something like this where the user can select the ID first and any date of his choice in the report.

[image: Report Parameters]

PS: I am not allowed to write in-line SQL and only SPs are allowed. I don't want to create two SPs for the same report.

Answer (score 0):

Use this stored procedure as the source of available values for the `UserID` parameter, and make sure that the `UserID` parameter comes **AFTER** the `ReportDate` parameter.  Then the `UserID` available values will not be populated until after the user chooses `ReportDate`.   Then this procedure will run using the user-selected `ReportDate`.

Also I think you need to remove the `@User_ID` parameter from your DataSet parameters (the last screenshot).   Your stored procedure only has the one `ReportRunDate` parameter.  The parameters in your SSRS dataset must match the parameters in the stored proc you are calling.

Regarding this error:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by
>   a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error.

It sounds like your stored procedure code was changed after you last edited your SSRS report, and now it doesn't return the expected values.   Use a profiler trace to see what command is sent from SSRS to your SQL Server, then execute that command in SSMS and look at the results.  What are the column names being returned?   Are they the same names in the `Fields` tab of your dataset?   Are they the same names as your `Value Field` and `Label Field` in your report parameter?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. The UserID dropdown list is showing some numbers that doesn't exist (say a -1 value or some 0s for example) in the actual result set from SP. Also, selecting the 'Available Values' option to retrieve the UserIDs is taking a lot of time to load into the drop-down list of SSRS.

Comment: OK, I've added screenshots to my OP.

Comment: I've added another screenshot at the end of the OP. Are you talking about that?

Comment: When I run the stored procedure in SSMS, I get the entire result set (what is needed). When I try to filter out that on the report based on ID, it doesn't work. When refreshed, I am getting the error _The expression used for the parameter'@User_ID' in the dataset '@User_ID' refers to a field. Fields cannot be used in query parameter expression_.

Comment: What is the expression you are using for the value of the @User_ID parameter?   Your screenshot only shows `<<Expr>>`

Comment: The value I'm having in the expression is **Fields!User_ID.Value**

Comment: I am confused now. Your first paragraph says to use `User_ID` parameter. And your second paragraph says to remove the `User_ID` parameter. If I remove the `User_ID` parameter, how do give an option to the customer to select a `User_ID` of his choice?

Comment: Ok, in the first paragraph, I am talking about the User_ID parameter of the report.  In the second paragraph I am talking about the User_ID parameter of the dataset.   This should be the dataset that is used to populate the User_ID parameter of your report.   This dataset should not have a User_ID parameter in itself.

Comment: Well, that was what I tried in the very beginning. I am getting the error _The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error._ when doing so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117008/discussion-between-julaayi-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using a stand alone SQL with advice from many experts to get the `User_ID`. I've added another parameter to the stored procedure and passing the second value to the parameter from the standalone SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UserInformation (@ReportRunDate DATE = NULL, @User_ID VARCHAR(10)) 
AS
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT -- some fields
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE RegisteredDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @ReportRunDate) - 2, -1)
AND UserID = @User_ID
--I'll output the result set after applying all the logic like

SELECT UserID, UserName, DOJ
FROM CTE
```

And, my standalone SQL looks something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY User_ID
```